# when to use wx.App and PySimpleApp

Tags: python, wxpython

i don't know where and when to use wx.App and PySimpleApp

like two code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx
import wx.py.images as images

class ToolbarFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Toolbars',
                size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('White')
class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = ToolbarFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
        frame.Show()
        return True
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()

    app.MainLoop()
```

and this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class ToolbarFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Toolbars',
                size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('White')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = ToolbarFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Are there have any difference?
another question other widget is at wx.Frame() or wx.App() like button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays there's almost no difference between these two classes.

When wxPython project started, `wx.PySimpleApp` and `wx.App` had different behaviour (the latter where more low-level and had not default `OnInit` method defined, while `PySimpleApp` was the class that could be just instantiated and put to do the job). Also some range of wxPython versions had `wx.App` class that had default `OnInit` defined but it didn't call `wx.InitAllImageHandlers` by default.

Now `wx.PySimpleApp` is left in API mostly for the reason of compatibility and there's not distinction between two classes.

Answer (score 0):

As of wx version 2.9 `wx.PySimpleApp` has been deprecated.

You should inherit the `wx.App` class in the first example noted in the question.

Or you should use `wx.App(False)` in place of PySimpleApp in the 2nd example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wx

class ToolbarFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Toolbars',
                size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('White')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = ToolbarFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```